# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn`t boot in dual-boot system

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

Ok, so... I'm not new to use linux but new to install it (before it I used live persistence mode). I have the notebook that have ssd disk partitioned on 2 partitions. One for disk C:\ and another one for programs and games. And HDD on 1 Tb for files. I free 280 Gb on that HDD and started to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop. I partitioned that free space on 2 partitions. One of them on swap and another one with mount point "/" in ext4 fs. Installation was succesfull. I rebooted my computer and get into GRUB2 where I was can Boot in Ubuntu or in the Windows. I chooce Ubuntu. It started to boot but it freezed Ubuntu boot screen. And I don`t know what to do, because I don't find anything about it.

Comment: sorry if I wrote something not correctly

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.